# Replace a substring

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have an input string. I need to replace its prefix (until first dot) with an other string.

The method signature:
    string MyPrefixReplace(string input, string replacer)
Examples:

```
string res = MyPrefixReplace("12.345.6789", "000")
res = "000.345.6789";

res = MyPrefixReplace("908.345.6789", "1")
res = "1.345.6789";
```

Is there a way ***not*** to extract a sub-string before first dot and make a Replace**? 
I.e - I don't want this solution

```
int i = input.IndexOf(".");
string rep = input.Substring(0,i);
input.Replace(rep,replacer);
```

Thanks

Comment: IndexOf() will give you the position, Substring() will allow you to chop that off

Comment: "I don`t want this solution" - Why?

Comment: What's wrong with `IndexOf` and `Substring`? (apart from the fact that you are taking the wrong part and `Replace` is not needed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public string MyPrefixReplace(string source, string value, char delimiter = '.')
{
    var parts = source.Split(delimiter);
    parts[0] = value;
    return String.Join(delimiter.ToString(), parts);   
}
```

[Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/evBW3Z)

Answer (score 2):

Using `String.IndexOf` and `String.Substring` ist the most efficient way. In your approach you have used the wrong overload of `Substring`. `String.Replace` is pointless anyway since you don't want to replace *all* occurences of the first part but only the first part.

Therefore you don't have to *take*  but to *skip* the the first part and prefix another. This works as desired:

```
public static string MyPrefixReplace(string input, string replacer, char prefixChar = '.')
{
    int index = input.IndexOf(prefixChar);
    if (index == -1)
        return input;
    return replacer + input.Substring(index);
}
```

Your input:

```
string result = MyPrefixReplace("908.345.6789", "1"); // 1.345.6789
result = MyPrefixReplace("12.345.6789", "000");       // 000.345.6789
```

Comment: +1 it did before the OP was edited (and is still the best way to do it)

Comment: @AlexK.: i haven't seen that OP has edited his question. He uses  the wrong overload of `Substring` and `String.Replace` is pointless. `String.Substring` is the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd split the string up to get around this problem, although there's obviously other ways of doing this, this would be my approach:

```
string Input = "123.456.789"

string[] SplitInput = Input.Split('.');
SplitInput[0] = "321";

string Output = String.Join('.', SplitInput);
```

Output should be "321.456.789".